# How to filter a specific text only when in front of it there is a number and such number is not known?

Tags: java, regex

I need a string to filter messages that contain a specific set of words in a definitive order (for instance "unread messages from") and that, at the same time, in front of such set of words have a number whose value is unknown (it could be 10 as well as 2000).

I will use it on Tasker, an Android app installed on my smartphone, so I would need the lightest and quickest string as possible. If it helps to simplify the logic, we can define the maximum number.

Comment: What regex string have you tried? Show us your attempt at solving this

Comment: \d unread messagges from \d chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close with your attempt, you just need quantifier:

```
\d+ unread messagges from \d+ chat
```

Comment: @Radeon89: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

you can use "unread messagges from \d+". 
it will match to "unread messagges from "

Comment: As per my first mesagge, I need to filter only those messagges with in front a number.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you can use the ^, which means that it only matches position at the beginning of the line. Therefore input 1a2 should output 1 with this regex:
`^\d+`